# How do I edit the drop down 'Sign In' option on One Page checkout for guest customers? - Magento 2.2

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.2, drop-downs

How do I edit the drop down 'Sign In' form on One Page checkout for guest customers in Magento 2.2?

- I preferably want to insert a CMS block just underneath the password box.
- This drop down is not a static block, it is not something I've created. 
  [image: Please help me]

Comment: @John did you try to customize in \Magento_Checkout\web\template\authentication.html ?

Comment: app\code\Magento\Customer\view\frontend\templates\account just as a note to anyone in future who can't find it where Piyush reccomends it

Comment: further note to self: the authentication-popup.phtml under app\code\Magento\Customer\view\frontend\templates\account is partially responsible and is the markup for the outskirts of the message, but the actual HTML can be found under app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/template/authentication-popup.html, something i got downvoted for a lot earlier even though I was correct :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the path of the file, you can enable template path hint from admin, it will display the file path in frontend.

To Enable template path hint Go to Admin panel, then Go to **Store->Configuration**. Now from left panel navigation select your store from top store view dropdown.

now under **ADVANCED** select **Developer**. After that Under **Debug** Section set **Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront** to **yes**

### Update

The login pop up comes from below file in luma theme

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't really work either as shown in this screenshot, https://imgur.com/xqj5uMi the sign in button (as highlighted in yellow in my screenshot) doesn't fall under any of these red lines, and the content itself that I want to change doesn't have a red line around it either.

Comment: @John check my updated answer

Comment: thank you for your updated answer, as it happens i'm using 2.2 and under my vendor/magento i have composer, magento-composer-install and zendframework1 i'm sure you're right but any idea where it's been relocated in 2.2?

Comment: it is on the same path in Magento 2.2, I am using the same version

Comment: i found it it's app\code\Magento\Customer\view\frontend\templates\account, i'm gonna accept your answer now, thank you! Sincerely appreciate it, you're the best!